# How do I get rid of extra information in a .s file?

Tags: assembly, gcc, compiler-optimization, compiler-explorer, godbolt

[image]When I use godbolt, I get a nice .s file containing only the assembly instructions, but when I use one of my toolchains, I get a lot of extra stuff I don't need for my project.

[image]

Anyway to get the same result as godbolt's?

Comment: godbolt filters output itself. It's not some option to the compiler.

Comment: All that stuff is still in the assembler output; godbolt just post-processes the output to filter it out.  If you deselect the "Directives" filter you will see it's still there.

Comment: Godbolt is [open source](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer) so if you care, you can find out exactly what they filter.  But what's your goal here?  Are you just trying to be able to read your own project's code more easily, or are you wanting to process it in some other way?

Comment: I need only the instructions, like, I get the same result as godbolts via objdump but it requires a few extra steps and looks redundant